# Hibernate composite foreign keys share column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

I'm working on a legacy database which I cannot change. This database regularly synches with secondary instances, which create new entries. To make an entity's primary key unique for all instances, all entities have composite primary keys consisting of the surrogate key generated by their original database and a server ID which identifies the original instance.

Composite primary keys are no Problem for Hibernate / JPA, it looks like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class ID implements Serializable {
    private Long autoin;      // Surrogate key
    private Integer serverId; // instance identifier

    @Column(name = "autoin_fix")
    public Long getAutoin() {
        return this.autoin;
    }
    @Column(name = "servdat_fk")
    public Integer getServerId() {
        return this.serverId;
    }

    // ... setter, equals, hashCode ...
}
```

Now consider the following Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LEADS")
public class Request {
    private Long id;

    private Article article;
    private Location location;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "autoin_fix")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "auto-increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "auto-increment", strategy = "sequence",
            parameters = @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "AUTOINCREMENT"))
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "artikel_fk", referencedColumnName = "autoin_fix", 
                    insertable = false, updatable = false), // Here is the problem!
        @JoinColumn(name = "servdat_fk", referencedColumnName = "servdat_fk", 
                    insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    public Article getArticle() {
        return this.article;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "standort_fk", referencedColumnName = "autoin_fix"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "servdat_fk", referencedColumnName = "servdat_fk")
    })
    public Location getLocation() {
        return this.location;
    }

    // Setters omitted
}
```

The Request entity has references to two other entities which both use the composite primary keys to identify themselves. But since from a business logic point of view, the serverId of both of these entities (Article and Location) **always have to be the same**, there is only one column for the serverId in the database:

```
TABLE leads
-------------
autoin_fix
artikel_fk
standort_fk
servdat_fk  // This only exists once, but is part of the association to both Article and Location!
```

To make the application start at all, I had to add insertable = false, updatable = false to the Article association, which is **not** what I want. If I try to persist a Request object, the field "artikel_fk" is not written, leaving a null in the database, since I told hibernate that it is read-only. And using insertable = false, updatable = false on just one of the join columns is not allowed either.

```
// This is illegal and the application won't start
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "artikel_fk", referencedColumnName = "autoin_fix"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "servdat_fk", referencedColumnName = "servdat_fk", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
```

Does anyone know a solution to this problem? Or is this impossible to map using Hibernate / JPA?

**EDIT:** The (simplified) definitions of Article and Location (really not that interesting, all that counts is that they use the composite primary key):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ARTIKEL")
public class Article {
    private ID id;
    private String headline;
    private String description;

    @EmbeddedId
    public ID getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Column(name = "artbesch")
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    @Column(name = "artueschr")
    public String getHeadline() {
        return this.headline;
    }

    // Setters omitted
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "STANDORT")
public class Location {
    private ID id;
    private GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates;
    private Name name;

    @EmbeddedId
    public ID getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Embedded
    public GeoCoordinates getGeoCoordinates() {
        return this.geoCoordinates;
    }

    @Embedded
    public Name getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    // Setters omitted
}
```

Comment: Can you post the definitions of Article and Location as we'll?

Answer (score 0):

I think that if the derived identifier of a dependent entity is in the form of an embedded id class, then each attribute of that id class that represents a relationship should be referred to by a @MapsId annotation on the corresponding relationship attribute.

For instance:

```
@Entity
public class Request {
    // ...
    @Id
    int id;

    @MapsId
    @ManyToOne
    private Article article;
    // ...
}
```

I hope that works, because I cannot try it in this moment.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow, but it looks promising.

Comment: The application starts now, but unfortunately hibernate tries to insert a new Article into the Database whenever I persist a Request, which results in a Primary Key violation since the Article already exists.
Do you know a fix for that as well?